# php function that generates queries to database

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

Very basic question, I am making functions that will generate queries to database. I have two approaches to this and I don't know which is better.

First is making one bigger function to generate any query I need, so basically:

```
function generateQuery($object, $queryType, $tableName, $conditions = null) {
    //Then in here some more complex code that generates query,
    //some of stuff like double if shorthands etc, for example:

    $string = ($queryType === "INSERT") ? "INSERT INTO {$table} (" : (($queryType === "UPDATE") ? "UPDATE {$table} SET" : "SELECT");

    //So all the code for generating INSERT, UPDATE and SELECT in one function
    //full of conditions.
}
```

Or I could just write seperate function for each type of query.

In the end, the first solution is not that complicated at all, and the second one would make some repetition in code, but still it does feel kind of wrong.

Then again I want to use PDO transactions later, so I will have a function like so:

```
function launchQueries($list) {
    $this->handler->beginTransaction();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++)
    {
        $this ->launchQuery($list[i]->object, $list[i]->$table, $list[i]->queryType, $list[i]->conditions);
    }
    $this->handler->commit();
}
```

Or something like that, not sure this exact code would work, since I haven't made it yet.

Anyway, with query generation in one function I can just pass queries in list and do one loop to generate and execute them all. But it still feels wrong. Is it done like this at all, or am I missing different, better solutions?

Comment: There is more than one way to skin a cat. No one answer will be be best in all situations.

Comment: The best way would be apparently **NOT**  to generate queries at all. SQL is far more rich language than you imagine. It is not limiter to a couple of silly operators.

Comment: I'm relatively new to the subject, so there is other way to do a operation on MySQL database in PHP, than to query a string in the end? No matter what operation I do it seems like the only medium between PHP and MySQL in the end is a query? Maybe my projects are to simple to go beyond queries? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: What YCS means is that SQL is not limited to [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations, but its power often lies in complex queries that will be quickly beyond the scope of what you can do with a roll-you-own code like the one you have above!

Comment: I understand now, I just read about the advanced operations and they seem to be useful and increase performance. But.. this app would be private and used by students of one faculty in university, so probably no more than 3000 simultaneous users. Couldn't I just pull it off with the basic CRUD operations? Seems like more advanced stuff is needed for bigger projects. Wouldn't I be overcomplicating and prematurely optimizing by doing more in sql rather than php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What feels wrong to me is reinventing the wheel.

What about using a solid, existing library such as [Doctrine DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html)?

It's cross-platform, and provides convenience methods such as [insert()](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#insert), [update()](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#update) and [delete()](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#delete):

```
$conn->insert('user', array('username' => 'jwage'));
$conn->update('user', array('username' => 'jwage'), array('id' => 1));
$conn->delete('user', array('id' => 1));
```

Comment: It is a college project, so unfortunately I need to reinvent the wheel. I guess I should have mentioned that. That is why my question wasn't about ready solutions, but about how to do it yourself. However I appreciate your answer, since I can see how things are done in this library.

Comment: Ok I understand. To see even more great ideas, have a look at the Doctrine [QueryBuilder](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.1/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Query.QueryBuilder.html), which allows you to build a SQL query in an OOP way.